# Jquery smoothscrolling - adding multiple exclusions

Tags: jquery

Newbie here :)

I have smooth scrolling on my page and I want to exclude 4 links.

Using the code below I can exclude one of the 4 links, how do I exclude the other 3?

I tried to get the 'or' operator to work and failed.

I tried a wildcard also.

The exclusions are #sample-3a #sample-3b #sample-3c #sample-3d

```
if (this.hash !== "#sample-3a") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
```

Any help would be appreciated - thank you :)

Comment: Strangely the and/or operator refused to work and disabled the whole page smooth scroll but using the var array has worked a treat thank you very much for your prompt responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
if (this.hash !== "#sample-3a" || this.hash !== "#sample-3b" || this.hash !== "#sample-3c" || this.hash !== "#sample-3d") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
}
```

---

As an alternative approach you can use an `array` or an `object` to keep the values and later inside the if condition check value present in it.

```
var ref = ['#sample-3a', '#sample-3b', '#sample-3c', '#sample-3d'];

// check value present in array
// you can also use `ref.indexOf(this.hash) == -1`
if (!ref.includes(this.hash)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
}
```

or with object reference.

```
var ref = { '#sample-3a': '', '#sample-3b': '', '#sample-3c': '', '#sample-3d': ''};

// check key present in the reference object
if (!(this.hash in ref)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to prevent scroll.

```
if(this.hash == "#sample-3a" || this.hash == "#sample-3b" || this.hash == "#sample-3c" || this.hash == "#sample-3d")
      {
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: `return false` is essentially the same as `preventDefault()` which OP says already works for `#sample-3a` - how does this answer the *actual* question: *"how do I exclude the other 3?"*

Comment: The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening and for other div check edited ans.